# Am I missing answers to my flags? Why?

Tags: support, flagging

During the time I have been active in this site, I have flagged this or that comment from time to time, adding my explanation of why I did that.

But I have never received any answer. I thought it was normal, but from reading some comments now, it seems that one should naturally expect some answer from somebody (moderators?). I have looked for any kind of menu within my profile, but I don't find any option such as an "Inbox" or something.

Are the moderators (or whoever) answering to my flags but I am missing them? If that is the case, how do I read such answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see a item "helpful flags" (and sometimes some unhelpful ones) in the fully informative version of your profile summary:

[image]

If you don't see it, you probably need to view the full information. Use "more info"

[image]

Once you can see it, click on the number of flags for a detailed list of how they were handled.

Or you can go directly to

```
http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/[your user ID]
```